# How to get namespace_id of existing group in GItLab via Terraform?

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-api

I'm using Terraform for creating a GitLab project.

I need this new project to be in a specific group.
I know the `name` and the `path` to this group, but I need to get `namespace_id`.

My config file:

```
resource "gitlab_group" "my_group" {
  name = "best_name"
  path = "https://gitlab.compony.com/best_name"
}

resource "gitlab_project" "terraform_01" {
  name         = "terraform_01"
  description  = "created by terraform"
  namespace_id = gitlab_group.my_group.id
  visibility_level = "private"
}
```

`terraform apply` returns:

```
gitlab_group.my_group: Creating...
╷
│ Error: POST https://gitlab.compony.com/api/v4/groups: 403 {message: 403 Forbidden}
│
```

I can't get more right for this group. Can I get `namespace_id` somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I stumpled upon a similar challenge.
I had to import the group into Terraform's state.

Try to run:

`terraform import gitlab_group.my_group best_name`

This will import the group "best_name" as the local resource "my_group" into your state.